# Changing the Border Radius and Height of a Mat Select Dropdown?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

In this [Angular Material Select dropdown demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y6mxsu-ttyaeo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.ts) I've inlined a border radius and height style change but it does not change the border radius or the height.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="border-radius: 25px; height: 10px">
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" panelClass="select-style">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping"
      >{{topping}}</mat-option
    >
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

How do we change the border radius and the height of the field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to target the form-field classes

Try the below code:

- add a `custom-field` class to the form field element
- using ng-deep override mat-form-field-flex, mat-form-field-outline-end and mat-form-field-outline-start classes

```css
::ng-deep .custom-field .mat-form-field-flex{
  height: 10px;
}

::ng-deep .custom-field .mat-form-field-flex .mat-form-field-outline-end{
  border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
}

::ng-deep .custom-field .mat-form-field-flex .mat-form-field-outline-start{
  border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px ;
  width: 25px !important;
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="custom-field">
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" panelClass="select-style">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping"
      >{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**For Material 15**

- Change the class names to mat-mdc-form-field-flex, mdc-notched-outline__trailing and mdc-notched-outline__leading

```css
.custom-field .mat-mdc-form-field-flex .mdc-notched-outline .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
  border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
}

.custom-field .mat-mdc-form-field-flex .mdc-notched-outline .mdc-notched-outline__leading {
  border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;
  width: 25px !important;
}
```

To centre the contents add these styles

```css
.custom-field .mat-mdc-form-field-flex {
  height: 42px;
  align-items: center;
}

.custom-field .mat-mdc-form-field-flex .mdc-notched-outline .mdc-notched-outline__notch label {
  top: 50%;
}

.custom-field .mat-mdc-form-field-flex .mdc-notched-outline .mdc-notched-outline__notch label.mdc-floating-label--float-above {
  top: 28px;
}
```

Comment: Hi - That looked promising.  I tried in in a new stackblitz and does not look like it's taking ... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y6mxsu-gsmzsd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.scss

Comment: updated the class names for material 15, please check

Comment: OK AWESOME!  That works!!  I noticed that when we change the height the select field does not recenter inside the new space.  Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: updated the answer with styles to center the content

Comment: Wow!!  Absolutely Brilliant!!  Thank you so much!!

Comment: This is the Angular 15 Demo just in case anyone needs it.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y6mxsu-pa2qn8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.html